# How can I make view in mysql using JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, view

There are two tables, table1 and table2.

[ table1 ]

```
+----+------+
| no | time |
+----+------+
| 1  | 1111 |
+----+------+
| 2  | 2222 |
+----+------+
| 3  | 3333 |
+----+------+
| 4  | 4444 |
+----+------+
| 5  | 5555 |
+----+------+
```

[ table2 ]

```
+----+-----+----------+------+
| no | idx | name     | rank |
+----+-----+----------+------+
| 1  | 1   | Apple    | 1    |
+----+-----+----------+------+
| 2  | 1   | Banana   | 2    |
+----+-----+----------+------+
| 3  | 1   | Car      | 3    |
+----+-----+----------+------+
| 4  | 1   | Dragon   | 4    |
+----+-----+----------+------+
| 5  | 1   | Eagle    | 5    |
+----+-----+----------+------+
| 6  | 2   | Fire     | 2    |
+----+-----+----------+------+
| 7  | 2   | God      | 3    |
+----+-----+----------+------+
| 8  | 2   | Hippo    | 4    |
+----+-----+----------+------+
| 9  | 3   | Icecream | 1    |
+----+-----+----------+------+
| 10 | 3   | Juice    | 3    |
+----+-----+----------+------+
| 11 | 3   | Korea    | 4    |
+----+-----+----------+------+
| 12 | 3   | Low      | 5    |
+----+-----+----------+------+
| 13 | 4   | Mother   | 2    |
+----+-----+----------+------+
| 14 | 4   | News     | 3    |
+----+-----+----------+------+
| 15 | 5   | Object   | 1    |
+----+-----+----------+------+
```

And, I want to make a view like follow image using mysql.

```
+----+-----+----------+------+------+
| no | idx | name     | time | rank |
+----+-----+----------+------+------+
| 1  | 1   | Apple    | 1111 | 1    |
+----+-----+----------+------+------+
| 2  | 1   | Banana   | 1111 | 2    |
+----+-----+----------+------+------+
| 3  | 1   | Car      | 1111 | 3    |
+----+-----+----------+------+------+
| 4  | 1   | Dragon   | 1111 | 4    |
+----+-----+----------+------+------+
| 5  | 1   | Eagle    | 1111 | 5    |
+----+-----+----------+------+------+
| 1  | 2   | Apple    | 2222 | 1    |
+----+-----+----------+------+------+
| 6  | 2   | Fire     | 2222 | 2    |
+----+-----+----------+------+------+
| 7  | 2   | God      | 2222 | 3    |
+----+-----+----------+------+------+
| 8  | 2   | Hippo    | 2222 | 4    |
+----+-----+----------+------+------+
| 5  | 2   | Eagle    | 2222 | 5    |
+----+-----+----------+------+------+
| 9  | 3   | Icecream | 3333 | 1    |
+----+-----+----------+------+------+
| 6  | 3   | Fire     | 3333 | 2    |
+----+-----+----------+------+------+
| 10 | 3   | Juice    | 3333 | 3    |
+----+-----+----------+------+------+
| 11 | 3   | Korea    | 3333 | 4    |
+----+-----+----------+------+------+
| 12 | 3   | Low      | 3333 | 5    |
+----+-----+----------+------+------+
| 9  | 4   | Icecream | 4444 | 1    |
+----+-----+----------+------+------+
| 13 | 4   | Mother   | 4444 | 2    |
+----+-----+----------+------+------+
| 14 | 4   | NEws     | 4444 | 3    |
+----+-----+----------+------+------+
| 11 | 4   | Korea    | 4444 | 4    |
+----+-----+----------+------+------+
| 12 | 4   | Low      | 4444 | 5    |
+----+-----+----------+------+------+
| 15 | 5   | Object   | 5555 | 1    |
+----+-----+----------+------+------+
| 13 | 5   | Mother   | 5555 | 2    |
+----+-----+----------+------+------+
| 14 | 5   | News     | 5555 | 3    |
+----+-----+----------+------+------+
| 11 | 5   | Korea    | 5555 | 4    |
+----+-----+----------+------+------+
| 12 | 5   | Low      | 5555 | 5    |
+----+-----+----------+------+------+
```

The range of `rank` column is 1 to 5.

And, If there is no data like (idx2 & rank5), then I want to use the data which has same `rank` and biggest `idx` and lower `idx` than that data.

I try to use following query.

```
select * from (`table1` JOIN (select 1 AS `rank` union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5) AS `x` )
```

But, I don't know how should I do in the future.

Comment: You should post textual data instead of images

Comment: @GurwinderSingh But, I cannot make a table using text :(

Comment: Have you tried doing anything ?

Comment: You can. [Look](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables)

Comment: @GurwinderSingh I have changed my question. Thank you for advice.

Comment: @Moudiz I have inserted my query in my question. Please check it again :)

Comment: @YouHoGeon can you explain to me more about the conditions ?

Comment: @Moudiz There are some omitted data like (idx=2, rank=1), (idx=2, rank=5), (idx=3, rank=2) or (idx=4, rank=1) in [table2]. I want to fill those so that, every number of rank is printed like [table3]. To fill omitted data, use another data which has same `rank` and biggest `idx`, but not larger than itself. English is not my native language. So, my explanation might be bad :(

Comment: I want to fill the rank column using the number 1 to 5.

Comment: okay now i understand what you want..give me few  minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
select ifnull(t2a.no, t2b.no) no, t.idx, ifnull(t2a.name, t2b.name) name, t.rank
from (
    select t3.idx, t1.no rank, (select max(idx) from table2 where rank = t1.no and idx<t3.idx) max_idx
    from (select distinct idx from table2 ) t3
    cross join table1 t1    
) t 
 left join table2 t2a on t2a.rank=t.rank and t.idx  = t2a.idx
 left join table2 t2b on t2b.rank=t.rank and t.max_idx = t2b.idx
order by 2,4
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, but It doesn't work. The result is like that. http://imgur.com/a/Em5Hj